# How to handle browser-specific types when used as property types?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Say you have a property like:

```
public intersectionObserver?: IntersectionObserver;
```

and you want to use Angular Universal, how do you handle this? With this you only get `ReferenceError: IntersectionObserver is not defined`.

I know that to check for the platform you can use:

```
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

...

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}

isBrowser() {
  return isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}

isServer() {
  return isPlatformServer(this.platformId);
}
```

to handle specific code but I have no idea how to handle properties, nor can I find any resources on the subject which I find bizarre.

How do you handle this?

Comment: Can you post the excerpt where you are using the property and getting the error?

Comment: @Eddi The error is very vague but I'm pretty sure it's this line `private observers = new Map<string, IntersectionObserver>();`.

Comment: So I guess you are getting a compile-time error by TypeScript? Then I would assume that that the symbol `IntersectionObserver` isn't available for your `tsconfig.server.json` configuration. You may need to add a specific type for that.

Comment: @Eddi Mmmh, shouldn't it be part of `dom` which is included by default in TypeScript projects? From `@types/web` package: "@types/web is also included inside TypeScript, available as dom in the lib section and included in projects by default."